# Pure анимация вращения CSS прерывается в бесконечном цикле

Tags: html, css3, html5, анимация, css-animation

У меня проблема с CSS-анимацией.

Хотел бы, чтобы моя анимация повторялась, но без потери начальных эффектов. Однако кажется, что в моем коде или в поведении CSS-анимации есть ошибка.

После завершения первых двух анимаций поворота (`spin`, `spinback`),  цикл начинается, но новая анимация уже не такая как раньше.

Моя цель состоит в том, чтобы создать анимацию поворота по 6 блоков по порядку, по одному за раз. Когда все блоки повернуты, они должны начать возвращаться в исходное состояние по порядку, один за другим.

```css
/* -------------------------------------------------------- */
#loader {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader1 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader1 .inner {
  animation: spin 10s ease 0s infinite, spinback 10s ease 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s ease 0s infinite, spinback 10s ease 10s infinite;
}

#loader1 .front {
  background-color: #db9834;
}

#loader1 .back {
  background-color: #3498db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader2 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader2 .inner {
  animation: spin 10s ease 1s infinite, spinback 10s ease 11s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s ease 1s infinite, spinback 10s ease 11s infinite;
}

#loader2 .front {
  background-color: #db8834;
}

#loader2 .back {
  background-color: #3488db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader3 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader3 .inner {
  animation: spin 10s ease 2s infinite, spinback 10s ease 12s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s ease 2s infinite, spinback 10s ease 12s infinite;
}

#loader3 .front {
  background-color: #db7834;
}

#loader3 .back {
  background-color: #3478db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader4 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader4 .inner {
  animation: spin 10s ease 3s infinite, spinback 10s ease 13s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s ease 3s infinite, spinback 10s ease 13s infinite;
}

#loader4 .front {
  background-color: #db6834;
}

#loader4 .back {
  background-color: #3468db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader5 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader5 .inner {
  animation: spin 10s ease 4s infinite, spinback 10s ease 14s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s ease 4s infinite, spinback 10s ease 14s infinite;
}

#loader5 .front {
  background-color: #db5834;
}

#loader5 .back {
  background-color: #3458db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader6 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader6 .inner {
  animation: spin 10s ease 5s infinite, spinback 10s ease 15s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s ease 5s infinite, spinback 10s ease 15s infinite;
}

#loader6 .front {
  background-color: #db4834;
}

#loader6 .back {
  background-color: #3448db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinback {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinback {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div id="loader1">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader2">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader3">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader4">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader5">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader6">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Просто, чтобы сделать его более понятным, я пытаюсь применить CSS метод `flipcard`:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

На div только для того, чтобы создать вид, что что-то загружается ...

Анимация только дает время для запуска ключевых кадров в правильное время, тогда в ключевых кадрах я вращаю div и помещаю время ожидания, пока другой div не завершит свое вращение. Таким образом, формула составляет 6 блоков за 10 секунд, что должно быть где-то между (от 0% до 100%), так что (`100/6 = 16,6`), поэтому я определяю для каждой анимации `16%` времени анимации от продолжительности общего времени анимации.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56682474/7394871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На enSO уже описывалась подобная проблема: [CSS3 Animate: How to have the object not revert to its initial position after animation has run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897724/css3-animate-how-to-have-the-object-not-revert-to-its-initial-position-after-an). Проблема в том, что в начале анимации объект возвращается к исходному состоянию. Но я решил проблему иначе: я просто соединил обе анимации в одну, и теперь оба разворота описываются одной функцией. Если вам обязательно нужны обе анимации, то переделайте, как сказано в вопросе на enSO. Вот мой код:

```css
#loader {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#loader1 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader1 .inner {
  animation: spin 20s ease 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 20s ease 0s infinite;
}

#loader1 .front {
  background-color: #db9834;
}

#loader1 .back {
  background-color: #3498db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader2 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader2 .inner {
  animation: spin 20s ease 1s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 20s ease 1s infinite;
}

#loader2 .front {
  background-color: #db8834;
}

#loader2 .back {
  background-color: #3488db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader3 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader3 .inner {
  animation: spin 20s ease 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 20s ease 2s infinite;
}

#loader3 .front {
  background-color: #db7834;
}

#loader3 .back {
  background-color: #3478db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader4 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader4 .inner {
  animation: spin 20s ease 3s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 20s ease 3s infinite;
}

#loader4 .front {
  background-color: #db6834;
}

#loader4 .back {
  background-color: #3468db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader5 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader5 .inner{ 
  animation: spin 20s ease 4s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 20s ease 4s infinite;
}

#loader5 .front {
  background-color: #db5834;
}

#loader5 .back {
  background-color: #3458db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader6 {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#loader6 .inner {
  animation: spin 20s ease 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 20s ease 5s infinite;
}

#loader6 .front {
  background-color: #db4834;
}

#loader6 .back {
  background-color: #3448db;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  58% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  58% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div id="loader1">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader2">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader3">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader4">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader5">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loader6">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="front"> </div>
      <div class="back"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Сначала я бы упростил ваш код и использовал бы меньше HTML / CSS. Тогда я бы рассмотрел только одну анимацию, где у меня будут оба состояния.

Анимация будет такой: первый щелчок, затем мы сохраняем первый цвет, затем второй снимок, затем мы сохраняем второй цвет. Он делится на 12 временных интервалов `(1 + 5 + 1 + 5)` `(1 + 5 = 6)`, что является количеством делений)

Если длительность равна `S`, то задержка должна быть кратна одному слоту `S / 12`. Обратите внимание, что я использовал перспективу внутри преобразования, чтобы избежать лишнего элемента:

```css
#loader {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#loader>div {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: spin 6s linear var(--d,0s) infinite;
}

#loader>div:before,
#loader>div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: var(--f,#db9834);
}

#loader>div:after {
  background-color: var(--b,#3498db);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader>div:nth-child(2) {
  --f: #db8834;
  --b: #3488db;
  --d:0.5s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(3) {
  --f: #db7834;
  --b: #3478db;
  --d:1s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(4) {
  --f: #db6834;
  --b: #3468db;
  --d:1.5s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(5) {
  --f: #db5834;
  --b: #3458db;
  --d:2s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(6) {
  --f: #db4834;
  --b: #3448db;
  --d:2.5s;
}


@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8.33%,
  50%{
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  58.33% {
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Связанные вопросы для более подробной информации о разнице между `perspective` и perspective()

[CSS 3d transform doesn't work if perspective is set in the end of property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51891329/8620333)

[perspective and translateZ moves diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54987891/8620333)

Мы можем упростить еще больше, если изменим окраску div при вращении вместо двух элементов. Изменение должно быть сделано в половине слота, где мы делаем переворот (первый и шестой) без какого-либо перехода `(transition)`, чтобы создать иллюзию:

```css
#loader {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#loader>div {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  animation: 
    spin   6s linear var(--d,0s) infinite,
    colors 6s linear var(--d,0s) infinite;
  background-color: var(--f,#db9834);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader>div:nth-child(2) {
  --f: #db8834;
  --b: #3488db;
  --d:0.5s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(3) {
  --f: #db7834;
  --b: #3478db;
  --d:1s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(4) {
  --f: #db6834;
  --b: #3468db;
  --d:1.5s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(5) {
  --f: #db5834;
  --b: #3458db;
  --d:2s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(6) {
  --f: #db4834;
  --b: #3448db;
  --d:2.5s;
}


@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8.33%,
  50%{
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  58.33% {
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes colors {
  0%,4.15% {
    background-color: var(--f,#db9834);
  }
  4.16% {
    background-color: var(--b,#3498db);
  }
  54.15% {
    background-color: var(--b,#3498db);
  }
  54.16% {
    background-color: var(--f,#db9834);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Еще одно упрощение можно сделать с помощью фильтра, учитывая тот факт, что вы хотите иметь одинаковые оттенки цветов:

```css
#loader {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#loader>div {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  animation: 
    spin   6s linear var(--d,0s) infinite,
    colors 6s linear var(--d,0s) infinite;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#db9834 50%,#3498db 0);
  background-size:100% 200%;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------- */

#loader>div:nth-child(2) {
  filter:brightness(0.9);
  --d:0.5s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(3) {
  filter:brightness(0.8);
  --d:1s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(4) {
  filter:brightness(0.7);
  --d:1.5s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(5) {
  filter:brightness(0.6);
  --d:2s;
}

#loader>div:nth-child(6) {
  filter:brightness(0.5);
  --d:2.5s;
}


@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  8.33%,
  50%{
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  58.33% {
    transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes colors {
  4.15% {
    background-position: top;
  }
  4.16%,
  54.15% {
    background-position:bottom;
  }
  54.16% {
    background-position: top;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Этот результат не совсем такой, потому что использовал случайный фильтр, но вы можете легко попробовать другой тип фильтрации, чтобы получить нужный результат.